# Scan input until input ==0 in C not working

Tags: c

My code allows for values to be input BUT it will only exit the loop if 0 is input 2 times. I am really lost about how to get rid of the duplicate input.

```c
scanf("%d\n", &n);

while(n!=0) {
    if (n!=0) {
        scanf("%d\n", &n);
    }
    else {
        //printf("%d\n",n);
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Keep things simple:

```
while(scanf("%d", &n) == 1 && n != 0)
{
   // ...
}
```